# zsh !! expands to the last but one command in history instead of the last one

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I would expect that `!!` in zsh should expand to the last command executed. The same as `!-1`. But in my zsh, it always expands to the last but one.

Example

```
~$ echo 1
~$ echo 2
~$ !!<tab>
```

The last `!!` simply expands to `echo 1`.

Is there any option that affect this?
What should I do to restore it?

Comment: What `$ZSH_VERSION` do you have? It works here in 5.0.2.

Comment: @jens, it is 5.3.1-dev-0

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the output of `setopt`?

Comment: @Jens thanks very much for your kind assistance. You inspired me to installed the newest version and after doing that the problem just is gone.